# Is a C1 uniformly continuous function Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis

I understand a uniformly continuous function is not necessarily Lipschitz, for example $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is uniformity continuous on $[-1,1]$ but is not Lipschitz due to that it has infinite derivative at $x=0$. So my question is, is we add an additional condition that the function is C1, then is it Lipschitz? If not, can you give a counter example? Thank you.

Comment: If it is $C^1$ over a closed interval (or any compact domain), then it is necessarily Lipschitz.  We can have $C^1$ non-Lipschitz functions over $\Bbb R$, however, that are uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you. Can you give an example of C1 non-Lipschitz functions over R?

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb R$. This function is $C^1$ but not Lipschitz...

Answer (score 2):

From the assumption that $f^\prime$ is bounded, you can derive that $f$ is Lipschitz. So each $C^1$ on a compact domain is Lipschitz. This does not be the case, if the domain of the function is not compact. Take $g: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb R: x \mapsto \tfrac 1x$ and $h: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R: x \mapsto x^2$ as counterexamples.